# different padding on sides on a viewport below 768px

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am making a website with block elements. When I go below 768 px the elements will have a border around them The padding on each side of the block elements is different. I need the sites to have the same padding on 5px. I tried to solve that with adding the code:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .row {
        margin-left: -5px;
        margin-right: -5px;
    }

    .row>[class*="col-"] {
        padding-left: 5px;
        padding-right: 5px;
    }
}
```

But does not solve the problem. Does anybody have an idea how I can solve this? (*When i paste in my HTML code in the Stackoverflow editor the div tags is jumping around. Sorry for this, I do not know why. So the html code looks quite messy*)

```css
/* Card and Button */

.index-content a:hover {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.index-content {
  /*margin-bottom: 20px;*/
  /*padding: 50px 0px;*/
}

.index-content .row {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.index-content a {
  color: black;
}

.index-content .card {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 1px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 2px 4px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.index-content .card:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 16px 24px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 6px 30px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 8px 10px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  color: black;
}

.index-content .card img {
  width: 100%;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  height: 350px;
}

.index-content .card h4 {
  margin: 20px;
}

.index-content .card p {
  margin: 20px;
  opacity: 0.65;
}

.index-content .blue-button {
  width: 100px;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 1s, color 1s;
  /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
  transition: background-color 1s, color 1s;
  min-height: 20px;
  background-color: #002E5B;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: lighter;
  margin: 0px 20px 15px 20px;
  padding: 5px 0px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.index-content .blue-button:hover {
  background-color: #dadada;
  color: #002E5B;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .index-content .col-lg-4 {
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .card {
    position: relative;
  }
  .card-content {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  }
  .card-content h4,
  .card-content p {
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 5px;
  }
  .card-content a {
    float: right;
  }
  .index-content .card h4,
  .index-content .card p {
    padding: 15px 20px;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .index-content .card p {
    padding: 0 20px 15px;
    margin: 0;
  }
}


/* GRID ELEMENTS */


/* Set width between block elements */

.small-padding.top {
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.small-padding.bottom {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.small-padding.left {
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.small-padding.right {
  padding-right: 5px;
}


/* Media quries */

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .small-padding.bottom {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .row {
    margin-left: -7.5px;
    margin-right: -7.5px;
  }
  .row>[class*="col-"] {
    padding-left: 7.5px;
    padding-right: 7.5px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="index-content">
    <div class="container">
      <a href="#">
        <div class="col-sm-12 small-padding bottom">
          <div class="card">
            <img src="https://image.ibb.co/nJ97Go/bmw.jpg"></img>
            <div class="card-content">
              <h4>BMW NEW MODELS</h4>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
              <a href="#" class="blue-button">Read More</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="index-content">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="col-sm-4 small-padding right bottom">
        <div class="card">
          <img src="https://image.ibb.co/iiWA2T/bmw_1.jpg"></img>
          <div class="card-content">
            <h4>BMW NEW MODELS</h4>
            <a href="#" class="blue-button">Read More</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-8 small-padding left">
        <div class="card">
          <img src="https://image.ibb.co/nJ97Go/bmw.jpg"></img>
          <div class="card-content">
            <h4>BMW NEW MODELS</h4>
            <!-- <p>Brødtekst</p> -->
            <a href="#" class="blue-button">Read More</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Check [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#how-it-works) - _In a grid layout, content must be placed within columns and only columns may be immediate children of rows._

Comment: So all my code is wrong? :-(

Comment: Not that it's _completely_ wrong, but you'll have to refactor some of html code. What version of bootstrap are you using?

Comment: Shoot... I was using so long time on trying to make the best code I could, and thought I was on the right track. I am using 3.3.7. Where do I start recoding?

Comment: Start from [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid-intro) for grid system.  Use this as a rule of thumb: `.container` > `.row` > `.col-*` > _your content_ (this is **not** a css selector - it's how you should place your elements).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.row>[class*="col-"]` is looking for any `class="col-` in the directly child of `.row`, your HTML is not structured like this. So remove the `>`

```
 .row [class*="col-"] {
      padding-left: 5px;
      padding-right: 5px;
  }
```

Or you also can set `.container [class*="col-"]`

Comment: That is solving the problem, thank you. Am I going out of the wrong track regarding using the bootstrap framework? I am afraid of doing some worng things, or hacking myself through a solution. I would like to lean up against the bootstrap framework as much as possible.

Comment: Bootstrap is a pretty good toolkit when you really understand its structure. So the documentation is the best place to learn it, https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/ ... Don't forget to set this answer as right.

Answer (score 2):

Why aren' you using [Bootstrap grid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/) classes? Then no custom CSS is required.

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12">
</div>
```

Comment: That is unfortunately not solving the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You must use bootstrap classes for all screen sizes if you use  `class="col-sm-8"` only is apply to medium screens, the correct use is:

```
<div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Still not working, so there must be some custom css on the card there is causing the problem?

Comment: Mmmm change the position of the div row, must be the parent of any col

Comment: Delete your custom css

Comment: And add this meta: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">

Comment: Is there a special reason I have to use the line `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">`? What is the difference compared to how the bootstrap framework is writing that:  `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`?

Comment: I use emmet for generate tags in sublime text if a write meta:vp i get that, for me no special reason.

Comment: but its important the structure .row>.col

Answer (score 1):

**JUST ADD** `!important` if you want to apply the same padding.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
        .row {
          margin-left: -5px !important;
          margin-right: -5px !important;
        }
        .row>[class*="col-"] {
          padding-left: 5px !important;
          padding-right: 5px !important;
        }

    }
```